# Changing what branch a merge is on without redoing the merge?

Tags: merge, mercurial

If somebody has merged branch B into branch A, but meant to merge A into B (so that the commit would be on branch B), is there a method I could use to get that merge (and all of it's descendents) into branch B? Besides redoing the merge, which was a considerable amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach should solve your issue, but is not really 'clean'.

1. Update to branch B (just before the merge).
2. Start a new merge with branch A. To avoid any interactivity, you can use 'hg merge --tool internal:local'. The actual merging doesn't matter, as you'll use the results from your previous merge.
3. Revert to the previous merge: `hg revert --all -r OLD_MERGE_CHANGESET`
4. Commit the merge.
5. Use 'hg rebase' to move all your later commits on top of the correct branch.

Comment: Instead of copying the contents around, you can just `revert --all -r` to the old merge, which properly tracks added/removed files.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a very good point, I don't know why I didn't just think of that :-) I'll update my answer to improve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you’ve just committed the merge, or if not, that the merge changeset 1. has no children and 2. is the parent of your working directory, then:

```
hg branch B --force
hg commit --amend
```